# How do I to load map when page is already loaded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have a page where I need to load a Map by an address to see the property located at that point. To do this I found the `Google Maps API` but I cannot do this works yet. I'm trying an example that I saw on documentation but it still doesn't works and does not throws any exception.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) de documentation.

How could I do this ?

**Loading Google Maps API**

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8JZPv2N9bE0OQABj6hKO9QZb0kH32l"></script>
```

**Script to Load Map By Address**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();
    codeAddress();   
});

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('myAddress').value;    
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="gmap"></div>

<!--my address-->
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.myAddress)
```

Comment: Do you see the alert error?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What is happening now ? Do you have any script errors ?

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved the problem.

```
function loadByAddress() {
    var address = $('#myAddress').val();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat, results[0].geometry.location.lng);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 20,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadByAddress);
```

Comment: What was the problem ?